# TypeError: Start must be an interger in python turtle drawing

Tags: python, syntax-error, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

so I'm trying to draw special-patterned square in python turtle, and I'm drawing odd line first due to the input of the user, if the type an odd number then it will be plus 1 and then divided by 2, else divided by 2, here's my code, and it shows this error when I'm trying to divide it

```
from turtle import *
color("blue"); speed(0)
from math import sqrt
edge = int(input())
line = int(input())
linenum = 3
def draw(edge,line):
    begin_fill(); rt(45); fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)/2); rt(90); fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)/2); rt(135); fd(edge); rt(90); end_fill()
    fd(edge); rt(180)
    begin_fill(); lt(45); fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)/2); lt(90); fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)/2); rt(135); end_fill(); fd(edge)
    
def base_square():
    global linenum
    draw(edge,line)
    pu(); fd(edge); lt(90); fd(edge); lt(90); pd()
    if line % 2 != 0:
        for i in range((line+1)/2):  
            for _ in range(linenum):
                draw(edge,line)
                rt(135); fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)); rt(45)
            pu(); bk(edge*(linenum+1)); rt(90); fd(edge*2); lt(90); pd()
            linenum += 2
    else:
        for i in range(line/2):  
            for _ in range(linenum):
                draw(edge,line)
                rt(135); fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)); rt(45)
            pu(); bk(edge*(linenum+1)); rt(90); fd(edge*2); lt(90); pd()
            linenum += 2


            
base_square()
```

Comment: ok but it's a bit long

Comment: Your question should include a [mcve]; in other words, just enough code to reproduce the error, and the _full_ error traceback, as that contains valuable information. As it stands, we have no idea what `start` refers to, other than knowing that it's meant to be an `int` and you've passed something other than an `int`

Comment: Please don't use `;` in Python. There's no glory in cramming a bunch of commands onto one line unless you're playing code golf. Please run your code through [black](https://github.com/psf/black) before posting here. It's available [online](https://extendsclass.com/python-formatter.html). I also suggest using the full turtle commands instead of the unreadable legacy logo abbreviations. Provide complete error messages. Thanks.

Comment: I thought it'd be long to not use ; and I'm not coding on python app, it's another app that my class use so we don't need to add those full turtle commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following:

```py
for i in range((line+1)//2):  
...
for i in range(line//2):
```

The `//` operator returns the integer quotient instead of a `float` type. `range` only accepts `int` type input.

Alternatively, because you're just running the same loop for both even and odd cases and only changing the number, all you have to do is

```py
for i in range((line+1)//2):
```

for both cases. This will give the same result whether or not it is even or odd. (e.g. `4//2 = 2`,`(4+1)//2 = 2`;`(5+1)//2` works as expected)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a for loop with a range which is not an integer. E.g,

```
for i in range("Potato"):
  do something
```

You must use an integer for this.

Looking at the code, you have

```
for i in range((line +1)/2):
```

but it looks like line+1/2 is not a integer, so the error is thrown.

Comment: but I use an if statement if line%2 !=0 then for i in range((line +1)/2): else just for i in range(line /2):

Comment: Yes, but lets say line + 1 is 3. Then line + 1 / 2 is 1.5. This is not an int, so the code will not run.

Comment: To fix it, you might want to just do `for i in range(int((line+1)/2))`